# scroll to end of text when click on input

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating input element.
I want to first click on input, text is selected all, and second click caret move to last position (caret always on last postion). I did it (see my code).

But when width of input less than value.length, at second click I can't see caret on IE 11.

How to scroll value to last position at second click?

My demo, open it on IE: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3SVZ4LTU7G5

```js
function selectAllText() {
     var input = document.getElementById("demo");
     input.setSelectionRange(0, input.value.length);
    }
    
    function moveEndCaret(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var input = document.getElementById("demo");
     input.setSelectionRange(input.value.length, input.value.length);
        input.focus();
    }
```

```css
input {
     padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <input id="demo" name="gender" value="123456789" type="tel" onfocus="selectAllText()"      onmousedown="moveEndCaret(event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your cursor is already at last, try moving cursor with arrow button, you can be able to spot it.

Comment: I want to scroll to last of text by code :(

Comment: `text-align: right`?

Comment: Did not get any solution using simple JS. If you are available to use JQuery than you can refer this code example. http://jsfiddle.net/esnvh/26/ It is working with IE.